# Filter out strings that are n-times in list

Tags: haskell

Given a list of strings and an integer c I want to filter out the strings that are c-times in the list. The problem is that I don't know how to take the next element in my function since I can't just take the first one, because then the function wouldn't work correct.

```
testfunc :: [String] -> Int -> [String]

testfunc list c              
       | (length(filter (==(head list)) list) == c) = testfunc (filter (/=(head list)) list) c
```

Comment: Not specific to this question: I see a lot of questions involving guards lately, leading to the use of partial functions and avoiding pattern matching. I wonder if some course/tutorial/book is focusing too much on guards, and prods programmers towards bad code. To instructors: consider banning the usage of partial functions (or just pretend they don't exist in the course -- when learning Haskell they do more harm than good, IMHO).

Comment: @chi maybe it's connected to the Hugs questions ... ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is ok for the elements in the returned list to be in different relative positions than they were in the original list, then you can easily (and with better performance) solve this with a combination of *sorting*, *grouping* and *concat*'ing:

```
testfunc list c = concat $ filter (\p -> length p /= c) $ group (sort list)
```

If you want to do it your way, you could use `drop` to skip the first element in the list (**this is wrong, see edit**):

```
testfunc list c
   | list == [] = []              
   | (length(filter (==(head list)) list) == c) = testfunc (filter (/=(head list)) list) c
   | otherwise = testfunc (drop 1 list) c
```

I'm note quite sure I understood your problem, so is this what you needed?

EDIT: Now I understand your issue, your function doesn't work correctly after taking the first element. If keeping order is important, you could try something like:

```
testfunc list c = filter (\s -> s `elem` validStrings) list
          where validStrings = map head $ filter (\p -> length p /= c) $ group (sort list)
```

Comment: Yeah it should defintly keep the original positions. Just erase all the strings that are n-times in the list. I tried your second solution, but now it doesnt terminate since I have to check if the all the strings were already processed by the function.

Comment: All right, let's work this out, for I'm a beginner too. Is this a very long list and is the number of distinct strings very large? If so, the algorithm *will* perform very badly. In that case, perhaps you should build a `Data.Map` with the counts per string, and then filter out the ones by looking up the Map.

Comment: No the list is normally not big and the algorithm also doesnt have to perform good. It just has to work. Maybe your 3rd solution does work, I didnt check it yet.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't check for the empty list first thing. It will never finish executing.